# Cassandra table that stops nodetool repair & export is slow

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a table that causes timeouts reading/writing the cluster when running "nodetool repair" and export (COPY FROM) functions are really slow (~150 rows/minute) with lots of GC errors in the log during the export.

Seems likely this is an issue with the schema as other tables with similar amounts of data (~ 1.5 million rows) behave normally.

Is there any obvious issue with this schema?

```
CREATE TABLE reportingtest.events (
    year int,
    month int,
    day int,
    hour int,
    action text,
    id uuid,
    attributes frozen<list<frozen<attribute>>>,
    domain text,
    organisation text,
    status text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((year, month), day, hour, action, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (day ASC, hour ASC, action ASC, id ASC)
```

The two UDTs used are:

```
CREATE TYPE reportingtest.attribute (
    namespace text,
    name text,
    displayname text,
    values frozen<list<frozen<attributevalue>>>
);
```

and

```
CREATE TYPE reportingtest.attributevalue (
    aggregationvalue text,
    extra frozen<map<text, text>>
);
```

So what am I doing wrong?

The cluster is running `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4].`

```
Percentile   Partition Size   Cell Count
50%          25109160         61214
75%          30130992         61214
95%          89970660         182785
98%          129557750        379022
99%          268650950        654949
Min          373              18
Max          464228842        113175
```

Comment: Run some query with `tracing on` and check how much tombstone generated

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There are no deletes on this table nor any updates so I'm not sure tombstones are the issue. Trying a few queries I get `Read 1000 live and 0 tombstone cells` each time.

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTablehisto.html - you should also check that your partitions are not "too huge"

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm. I'm thinking a 200mb partition and a max of 500mb could be "too huge"? (I read somewhere 100mb is optimal). Seems I need to change the partition key then?

Comment: `Percentile    Partition Size        Cell Count
50%             25109160             61214
75%             30130992             61214
95%             89970660            182785
98%             129557750            379022
99%             268650950            654949
Min              373                        18
Max             464228842           113175` Sorry - not sure how to format that in a comment.

Comment: can you include the trace output in question and cfstats output too if possible? Also how big is your heap (Xmx) ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after lots of testing I found that the issue is maybe two fold:

1) When exporting a table with a text field that contains JSON the COPY TO job slows down significantly. I proved this my populating the table with 50000 records with a JSON field and then the same table with records where the text was just repeated characters to the same length as the JSON. COPY TO runs at ~800/s for the former and ~3000/s for the latter. I'm thinking this is something to do with the way the COPY TO has to escape the output in the CSV - though changing the delimiter didn't seem to help.

2) Seems the nesting of the collections (here using the UDTs but also happens without them) was causing issues with the repair job. I proved this by removing the nesting and using a text field containing the JSON instead (mapping to the types is then handled in the application). Repairing this table now is near instant after first run (4 minutes on first run to do 1.5M rows and then 1 second after that).

Regarding nesting, trying frozen>>> seemed OK, trying frozen>>>>> resulted in sub-100/s export times.

So avoiding nesting collection I guess!